# Hard disk ticks when laptop is idle

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, hard-drive-failure

I have an about 3 years old laptop, but very well maintained, and it stared a few weeks ago making a quit tick when it's idle. It sounds like an hard disk tick. It's really rare, it happens 3-4, max 5 times a day and only when the laptop is idle.

Should I be worried that it may be failing?

Comment: Your SMART tool says?

Comment: What do you mean by `it sounds like an hard disk tick`? Is it loud? Is it unusual? Does it sound like the normal noise the drive makes when it is being used? Have you checked the [SMART](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) data? Are you sure it’s *only* when it’s idle?

Comment: I never used smart tools until now. Do you now a good smart tool for windows?

Comment: Maybe this could be of some use http://www.ngohq.com/news/19805-critical-design-flaw-found-in-wd-caviar-green-hdds.html

Answer (score 0):

you could remove the harddrive cover underneath and listen for when it makes the noise. This will help to identify whether it is the hard drive or not. Hard drives have an unknown life, some can fail after a week or a month, some can last many years. It's tricky to tell. As other comments have said, the SMART utilities should say whether there is an error in the disk but may or may not. Any odd noise I hear, if I confirm it's the hard disk I backup straight away. Then at a convenient time I'd replace it to be safe. Particularly if you have data that you're worried about. Hard drives are very cheap and it's better to be safe than sorry.

If you don't store important data on it, then you can let it run on because it could continue to work fine for years, but again, hard drives are cheap

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, it's incredibly likely that your hard drive is failing. Although I have seen in a few cases where the harddrive will make funny noises for years, but more often than not they die within a few months. Because a some manufacturers have 3 and 5 year warranties, I would remove the hard drive then go to the manufacturer's website to see if it's still under warranty. If it is, then you'll wanna act sooner rather than later regarding your following efforts. After that I would run a diagnostic tool like one of the one's on Hiren's Boot Disc (http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd) preferrably one by the manufacturer of the hard drive. Once you've done that it should tell you whether or not you have reason to be concerned. If it's telling you there's any sort of problems, I would request an RMA from the manufacturer for replacement (MAKE BACKUPS!!!) or replace it if it's not under warranty.